# Keeping two elements inline on responsive display

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a strip comprised of four boxes side by side which will turn to two by two when displayed on responsive screens. I used two tables with 2 columns to do so but I get width problems. Tried to add widht:100%; but no effect. Tried to replace the tables with spans but they get stacked one on top of the other when re sizing the screen.

My site url is [here](http://gurtech.guywalderonline.com/index.php/he/) and you can see the four boxes on the home page.

On Chrome it looks great but on any other browser it runs out of the frame.

This is the code I used to construct the tables:

```html
<div style="margin-left: -7px;">
    <table dir="rtl" align="center">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="greyboxhp">
                        <p style="text-align: center;" dir="rtl"><span style="color: #000000;"><a href="#"><span style="color: #000000;">Box 1</span> </a>
                            </span>
                        </p>
                        <p style="text-align: center;" dir="rtl">
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/fields/Field1.png" alt="Field1" />
                            </a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <p class="readmore" style="text-align: center; margin-top: -17px;">
                        <a class="btn" href="/index.php/page1"> <span class="icon-chevron-right"></span> Read more... </a>
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="greyboxhp" style="margin-right: 10px;">
                        <p style="text-align: center;" dir="rtl"><span style="color: #000000;"><a href="#"><span style="color: #000000;">Box 2</span> </a>
                            </span>
                        </p>
                        <p style="text-align: center;" dir="rtl">
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/fields/Field2.png" alt="Field1" />
                            </a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <p class="readmore" style="text-align: center; margin-top: -17px;">
                        <a class="btn" href="/index.php/page2"> <span class="icon-chevron-right"></span> Read more... </a>
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code. 1. It will be easier to spot the problem. 2. Once you'll fix you site your "example" link won't be relevant.

Comment: Edited to include a snippet

Comment: Why do you use tables to order those 4 divs?

Comment: I need them to keep the same aspect ratio and when re sizing the screen to responsive layout (mobile) I need them to be placed two elements side by side and on top of the other two. You can see it in Chrome if you would like an example to what it is I wish to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for a cross-browser way to make the `<div>`s split break too the next line like I did in

### [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g12g80pj/).

I wrapped them in a span, and used the CSS `white-space: nowrap;` property to acheive this.  This will be much more effective than a table.

It works on all browsers.  Hope this helps!

Comment: That is EXACTLY What I needed. Thank you so much for that. It's really much more elegant this way.

Comment: Well, I've used your solution with some design changes of my own. It works fine until I try to add my read more button. When I add the button the with of the button (which I can't find how to manipulate) pushes the other box down :(

Comment: Solved by inserting the Read More element inside the box. Thanks.